# How do I sync music from library onto new phone?

Tags: iphone

I bought an iPhone 6+ and want the music from my library to reside on the phone.  How do I get it to sync and actually download the music to the phone?  I do not use the iCloud for backup.

Answer (score 2):

Best, and easiest way to get music onto your new iPhone is by syncing it with your iTunes library.

When you connect your phone to your computer, an iPhone icon will appear in iTunes.

Click the iPhone icon, and then a list of the different types of media will appear on the left.

Select "Music" and then select which songs, albums, artist, or playlists you wish to sync with your phone.

Click Sync in the bottom right corner, and let the phone complete the syncing process.